Minimum Number of Edges in a Connected Graph with Articulation Points and Biconnected Components
I am encountering this question and I would like to seek out for some opinion
"Suppose you have a connected, undirected graph G=(V,E) with:

n vertices,

one articulation point

t biconnected components, where ( 2 <= t <= n-2 )


The goal is to express the minimum number of edges in G as a function of n and t."
Here’s how I approached finding the minimum number of edges for this type of graph:
To minimize edges, I assumed each biconnected component should only have two vertices connected by a single edge. Since there are t biconnected components, this gives t edges inside those components. Each of these t components then needs to connect to the single articulation point with one edge each, which adds another t edge.
This results in E=2t edges in total.
Given that n=2t+1 (two vertices per component plus the articulation point), I found t in terms of n as t=(n-1)/2
Substituting this, the minimum number of edges E becomes: n+(t/2)
I'm somewhat uncertain about my approach because minimizing each biconnected component to just two vertices seems efficient, but I’m not entirely confident this setup yields the absolute minimum for all possible configurations. Simplifying to the smallest structure might overlook other valid configurations that still meet the constraints with slightly different edge counts. General formulas can sometimes fail for small cases, and the lack of counterexamples makes me wonder if I’m missing any edge cases.
Any insights to confirm or improve this approach would be helpful. Thank you!

Does an articulation point mean a cut-vertex?

yes that is correct

First of all, the biconnected components are not vertex-disjoint; they're edge-disjoint. In fact, they must all overlap at the cut vertex. Therefore if all the biconnected components have only $2$ vertices, then $n=t+1$ rather than $n=2t+1$. This is the case of the star graph $K_{1,t}$. It has $t = n-1$ edges.
But this is not a complete solution, because we cannot simply assume any relationship between $n$ and $t$. We have to be able to answer a question such as, "Suppose $n=100$ and $t=3$; what is the minimum number of edges?" If we get a relationship $n=t+1$ from assuming that all biconnected components have only $2$ vertices, then all we've learned is that when $n\ne t+1$, the structure must be more complicated.
In general, a biconnected component with $k>2$ vertices must have $k$ edges. So if we split up the $t$ biconnected components into $t_1$ $2$-vertex bicomponents and $t_2$ larger bicomponents, then:

The $t_1$ small bicomponents account for $t_1$ non-cut vertices, and have $t_1$ edges.
Therefore the $t_2$ large bicomponents must account for the remaining $n - t_1 - 1$ non-cut vertices. They also include the cut vertex $t_2$ times. So their total number of vertices is $n-t_1-1 + t_2$, and that's also how many edges they have.
Altogether, there are $t_1 + (n - t_1 - 1 + t_2) = n+t_2-1$ edges.

We minimize this by making $t_2$ as small as possible, but we know that when $n \ne t+1$, we cannot set $t_2 = 0$. So in that case, we should set $t_2 = 1$.
The resulting graph looks like a cycle of length $n-t+1$, with $t - 1$ leaves added to a single vertex of that cycle. It has $n$ edges: this is the minimum when $n \ne t+1$.
